# Simple 3 Page Hyperlink Graph

Tags: graph, hyperlink

I am learning from: https://github.com/louridas/pagerank

Can someone please help me understand what a Simple 3 Page Hyperlink Graph might look like in a Data Structure.

[image]

If we had to visualise this in say Excel, how would we represent this in a Hyperlink Graph?

Answer (score 0):

A very good description here: [Lecture #3: PageRank Algorithm](http://www.math.cornell.edu/~mec/Winter2009/RalucaRemus/Lecture3/lecture3.html)

```
double[] NodeA = new double[] { 0.0, 0.2, 0.2 };
double[] NodeB = new double[] { 0.0, 0.0, 0.2 };
double[] NodeC = new double[] { 0.4, 0.0, 0.0 };
```

In Excel:

```
0.0, 0.2, 0.2
0.0, 0.0, 0.2
0.4, 0.0, 0.0
```